# Are microSD cards software lockable?

Tags: storage

I have a .Net Micro Framework app that is failing to write bytes to a microSD card. When I take the card out of the device and look at it on my PC using a microSD to SD adapter the PC cannot write to the device as it appears to be locked. I'm trying to work out if the lock is a faulty adapter (the switch on the side of the adapter is set to the unlocked position) or the sate of the microSD card itself.

MicroSD cards have no visible way of locking and unlocking them but is there any setting in the card itself that locks it?

I have tried searching but most threads I can find (e.g. this one and this one, to choose two SO ones) talk about the adapter. Is there locking in the microSD specification?

Comment: While an interesting question, it seems better suited to a non-programming stack. (Anyway, is the Filesystem itself mounted as R/W or does it show a read-only media?)

Comment: Any suggestions as to which one?

Comment: http://superuser.com/

Comment: [Done](http://superuser.com/q/785103/166855). Interestingly [the answer there](http://superuser.com/a/785104/166855) makes me think that this is on-topic for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Duskwuff](https://superuser.com/users/89623/duskwuff) gave [an answer on the SuperUser SE](https://superuser.com/a/785104/166855), pointing out that:

"most computer-based SD card adapters are unable to execute arbitrary commands on an SD card" but that there are commands "available to (and used by) embedded devices"

Commands such as `CMD27 (PROGRAM_CSD)` "can be used to set bits which control temporary or even permanent write protection" and `CMD42 (LOCK_UNLOCK)` "can even be used to turn on and off password-based read protection".

There are more details about these register commands in [Appendix C.1 SD Mode Command List](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/pls/simplified_specs/archive/partE1_300.pdf) of Part E1 of the SDIO Simplified Specification